# how to find dropped calls in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Is it possible with iPhone 4 or 3gs to find the number of dropped calls programmatically ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think the official SDK allows this.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in jailbreak iPhone. using shell-script. u can't do it in official SDk.

Answer (score 1):

There is no access to the call log from Cocoa Touch or other iPhone APIs unless its jail-broken